# Should we replace the [taskscheduler] tag with [scheduled-tasks]?

Tags: discussion

The [taskscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskscheduler) tag has only 210 questions and only 5 followers, while the [scheduled-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks) tag has 4.3k questions and 55 followers.  I have even seen them used togther.  Should we simply remove the first tag and update all existing questions to point to the second?

Comment: @Kendra edited as noted, though I'm not stoked about the `[tag:tagname]` outcome, as I'd prefer they link to the wiki pages, but sometimes convention should be preferred to correctness.

Comment: In other words, an alias: [tag:taskscheduler] -> [tag:scheduled-tasks]?

Comment: @Cerbrus an alias would be fine, but for 210 questions and 5 followers I'd rather have only one.

Comment: The alias would automatically replace the left tag with the right one, afaik.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are correct sir. "[Tag Synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) **will be automatically and silently changed**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Task Scheduler is probably what [taskscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskscheduler) was created for (though that's only a guess, since it has no usage guidance on the tag wiki). A brief glance at the first page or two of that tag seems like those questions are *all* about the Windows Task Scheduler.

On the other side, [scheduled-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks) is much more broad, covering the simple act of scheduling a task in any program, in any language, or on any platform.

I'm not sure whether we should combine them; you could make the argument that anyone browsing [scheduled-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks) would be familiar with the Windows Task Scheduler, but I'm hesitant to say that's the case.

Just based on the tag numbers, it looks like there are a lot more people familiar with scheduling and automating tasks in general than there are people familiar with using or solving problems related to the Windows Task Scheduler, specifically. Perhaps we should have [taskscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskscheduler) renamed to [windows-taskscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-taskscheduler) to clarify?

Edit - looking now I see there's also [windows-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-scheduler) as well, with 76 questions, which refers to the Windows Task Scheduler. We should probably re-tag all the [taskscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskscheduler) questions to either [windows-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-scheduler) or [scheduled-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks), in my opinion. At ~210 questions, this shouldn't be too tall an order for someone with 3k+ reputation.

Comment: But the scheduled-tasks tag itself refers to the Windows Scheduler so by definition of the tag anyone following it already is.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Yes, it does, because it's a broad encompassing tag. There are many cases on the site where broad tags also cover more specific niche tags. The value of a niche tag can be removing noise about orthogonal subjects. If Windows Task Scheduler were just a kind of scheduled task and not a whole program with its own services, I'd say definitely combine it.

Comment: But in general we don't ask on SO about how to use a specific program.  Windows Task Scheduler usage would be a much better fit for SuperUser, no?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake We ask all the time how to use a specific program if that program is used primarily for programmatic things or is used primarily by programmers. But see my edit - seems an alternate solution has presented itself.